# Breeze + OData + Web Api versus Breeze + Web Api

Tags: odata, breeze, asp.net-web-api

The new sample at http://www.breezejs.com/samples/breeze-web-api-odata explains:

*Breeze abstracts the details of its own communications with the server into a "DataService Adapter". The default adapter is designed for a Breeze-flavored ASP.NET Web API ... which is not the same stack as the Web API 2 OData.*

I would like to know what are the arguments that would favor either of these two stacks.

Comment: Also see the last section on this page: http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata

Comment: Thanks - this is the information I was looking for, so I am going with breeze and "straight" web api (http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Breeze website, there is a special section about the differences between the two;
http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata-vs-webapi

Additionally, OData is a standard for consuming web APIs, means if an API supports OData, it recognizes keywords like these when you want to query it; $expand, $select, $filter, $orderby, $skip, $top etc.

For instance, you can write a query like this against an OData API;
/odata/Customers?$expand=Orders&$filter=City eq 'Amsterdam'&$orderby=CreatedOn

Which will bring you the Customers together with their Orders from Amsterdam city by ordering the results using CreatedOn field.

Of course there are many details about it. You can have more info from its website;
http://www.odata.org/

Comment: Thank you Serkan, particularly for the link http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/odata-vs-webapi

Comment: @nikivancic Sure, no problem. Could you accept the answer, so it will not be filtered as unanswered?